# How to solve $\min(x^2+y^2)$, $x\ge1, y\ge-2$, using the KKT conditions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm trying to understand better optimisation problems and in particular the KKT conditions. To this end, consider the minimisation problem
$\min(x^2+y^2)$ subject to $x\ge1$ and $y\ge -2$.

It's clear that the solution is $x=1, y=0$. However, how do I get this by applying the KKT conditions? And is this a kind of problem where they are necessary and sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this in the process of writing up the question, so I figured I'd post it for future reference and in case it might help someone else.

Define the Lagrangian
$$L(x,y,\lambda,\mu) = x^2+y^2-\lambda(x-1)-\mu (y+2).$$
Imposing $\nabla L=0$ you get the conditions $2x=\lambda$ and $2y=\mu$.
From this we can see that

1. If $\mu\neq0$, then $y=-2$, thus $\mu=-1$, which isn't consistent with $\mu\ge0$.
2. If $\mu=\lambda=0$ the only solution would be $x=y=0$ which isn't feasible.
3. If $\mu=0$ and $\lambda\neq0$, then $x=1$, $\lambda=2$. But also from $2y=\mu$ we'd get $y=0$. The corresponding cost is $1^2+0^2=1$, and therefore this is the solution I know I should have got from the beginning (my initial problem is that I did some miscalculations in this step and didn't correctly get this solution as I expected).

For completeness, we can also verify what the dual problem looks like. We have
$$g(\lambda,\mu) \equiv \inf_{x,y} L(x,y,\lambda,\mu)
 =
\inf_{x,y}[x(x-\lambda) + y(y-\mu) + \lambda-2\mu]
\\ = -\frac14\lambda(\lambda-4) - \frac14\mu(\mu+8).$$
Maximising this in the dual feasible set, $\lambda,\mu\ge0$, we easily get the solution
$\sup_{\lambda,\mu\ge0} g(\lambda,\mu) = g(2,0) = 1$, which matches the primal solution, hence confirming strong duality.

Finally, it's worth noting that the Slater conditions are *not* satisfied in the case, as one of the inequalities is active on the solution. However, I think the LICQ constraint is satisfied, being the gradients of the constraints linearly independent, which is consistent with KKT correctly producing the solution.